# How to assign value in stored procedure variable when executing it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL code

```
CREATE PROC sp_procedure 
     (@Name VARCHAR(50), 
      @Stock numeric)
AS 
    DECLARE @Code CHAR(4)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbProcedure 
    SET Name = @Name, Stock = @Stock 
    WHERE Code = @Code

    SELECT * FROM tbProcedure
END
```

Then I execute the code like this

```
EXEC sp_procedure 'Name',15,2
```

Then I got error result saying too many argument specified.

I also tried this

```
EXEC sp_procedure 'Name',15
```

It doesn't return an error, but 0 rows affected.

I want to assign `@Code` value when I execute the stored procedure, is it even possible to do that ?

EDIT:

Sorry, it's actually a `CHAR(4)`, not `INT`

Again sorry, I just copy paste all code without looking at it first, above is the actual code, I am very sorry for the confuse...

Comment: The first parameter of your stored procedure is declared as an int, so why are you passing the string value 'Name' ?

Comment: So many things here. First you define numeric but do not specify the scale or precision. Do you know the default size? I know I can't remember and even if I did I do not like to rely on defaults. Provide a scale and precision. What is @Code? It is a defined local variable that is always NULL...as a result your code is likely not doing what you want. Then you have the sp_ prefix, this is a no win. I would suggest a different prefix, or even better, no prefix at all. Last but not least, when calling a procedure you should specify which value is for which parameter...again don't rely on defaults.

Comment: do not start the procedure with sp_    Check here for more info https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: where does the vairable code should get its value from ?

Comment: sorry, i am already edited it , above is my actual code

Comment: still don't know where the `@code` should get its value from

Comment: @EinHazard Just look at it. Code is obviously meant to be a parameter, as it stands there is no way to set a value to it, and therefore your code will never do anything!

Comment: yes, that is way i ask, is it even possible for declared variable value to be assigned when i am executing the procedure ?

Comment: You can set a variable inside the stored procedure, but you can't access it from outside the SP unless it's a parameter. You could for example set @Code to a static value, or say something else based on a parameter

Comment: I see... then can you assign parameter that we are not create in procedure ? example i have 3 field in table : 
Code, Name and Stock. and in Procedure i put 2 Parameter : 
Name and Stock , 
as 
update from tbitem set name =@name, stock=@stock where Code=@Code 

So, can i call it like this ? 

'item 1',25,2

So it will update item where code is 2, but I don't make a Parameter
for it, is it possible to do something like that ?

Comment: Why can't you make it a parameter? If you did, your example would work fine.

Comment: @Bridge Because i want to make it a branch using IF, that is why the first code have a parameter Choice, but if i make Code into a parameter it wouldn't work with the insert syntax code since i am using custom auto number using declared variable that i make the name Code. So if i make a parameter it MUST be used in insert syntax even thought iam using custom auto number using declared variable, and if i do not make a parameter, it will return error in update syntax since it do not have a Code parameter to fill in....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a conclusion that its impossible to combine branching stored procedure if one of the branch do not use all the parameters.

And because of that I have write 2 stored procedures, below is my full code :

For insert procedure:   [this is the procedure that using a variable]

```
CREATE PROC InsProcedure
     (@Name VARCHAR(50), 
      @Stock numeric)
AS 
    DECLARE @CODE INT
    DECLARE @CODE2 CHAR(4)

BEGIN
    // Creating custom auto number
    SET @CODE = 0

    SELECT @CODE = ISNULL(MAX(CAST(KodeBarang AS INT)), 0) 
    FROM tbProcedure

    SET @CODE2 = @CODE + 1
    SET @CODE2 = REPLICATE('0', 4 - LEN(@CODE2)) + @CODE2
    // End Custom auto number

    INSERT INTO tbProcedure VALUES(@CODE2, @Name, @Stock)           

    SELECT * FROM tbProcedure
END
```

For update, delete, and show procedure:

```
CREATE PROC OtherProcedure 
     (@choice int, // this is for branching option later
      @Code CHAR(4),
      @Name VARCHAR(50), 
      @Stock numeric)
AS  
    IF @choice = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tbProcedure 
        SET Name = @Name, Stock = @Stock 
        WHERE Code = @Code

        SELECT * FROM tbProcedure
    END
    ELSE IF @choice = 2
        DELETE FROM tbProcedure 
        WHERE KodeBarang = @Code        
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM tbProcedure
```

and use the procedures like this :

```
InsProcedure 'Laptop', 5
```

Result:

```
00001, Laptop, 5
```

Branch 1 [Update]

```
OtherProcedure 1, 'Laptops', 10, 00001
```

Result:

- Before : 00001, Laptop, 5
- After  : 00001, Laptops, 10

Branch 2 [Delete]

```
OtherProcedure 2, '', 0, 00001     // Delete record where Code is '00001'
```

Branch 3 [Show]

```
OtherProcedure 3, '', 0, 0     // You can also use any number besides 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are providing the parameters in a different order than you have declared them.  Choice is declared before Name but you are providing Name first when executing the procedure.  Also, don't you want your update statement to say "code = @choice"?  The local variable is undefined and not needed.

Answer (score 1):

*For Microsoft SQL Server*

For your problem:
(don't use sp prefix) and (@code is not a parameter so we cannot pass value, it is local variable)
If you are having some problems with IF then, make @code as parameter but pass null value when needed and make that null check in procedure.

See below to assign values:

```
USE [databasename]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = <procedurename>
        @stringvariable = N'<stringvalue>',
        @Flag = <integervalue>

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value (return value if any)

GO
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, your variable @Stock doesn't return decimal because it's INT variable, you might try float or something else. It's the reason why it shows an error if you give it "15,2"

```
WHERE Code = @Code
```

And 0 rows affected was caused because you didn't set that variable properly. 
You have to assign a valid value to it.

Comment: um.. no, its actually 15 for 'stock' and 2 for 'Code'. not 15,2 for Stock